# HEIC operations with ImageMagick produce invalid output

Tags: macos, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, heic

These operations works:

- HEIC to other formats, e.g. convert IMG_8293.HEIC c.jpg

These operations produce invalid output:

- convert any format to HEIC, e.g.: convert c.jpg c.heic
- rotate HEIC: convert IMG_8293.HEIC -rotate 90 IMG_8293.HEIC
- other HEIC operations, e.g. flip, flop, etc.

Invalid output means: the metadata are shown properly but MacOS preview complains: "`The file “c.heic” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.`".

The metadata of the input file c.jpg

```
c.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 72x72, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=11, manufacturer=Apple, model=iPhone 11 Pro, orientation=upper-left, xresolution=166, yresolution=174, resolutionunit=2, software=14.0.1, datetime=2021:06:15 17:59:12, GPS-Data], baseline, precision 8, 3024x4032, components 3

ExifTool Version Number         : 12.26
File Name                       : c.jpg
Directory                       : /Users/pepa/Downloads/imageTests/a
File Size                       : 3.4 MiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:06:21 14:45:17+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:06:21 14:55:02+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:06:21 14:55:01+02:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPhone 11 Pro
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : 14.0.1
Modify Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exposure Time                   : 1/60
F Number                        : 1.8
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 125
Exif Version                    : 0231
Date/Time Original              : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Create Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Offset Time                     : +02:00
Offset Time Original            : +02:00
Offset Time Digitized           : +02:00
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/60
Aperture Value                  : 1.8
Brightness Value                : 3.03912093
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm
Subject Area                    : 2002 1505 2213 1324
Run Time Flags                  : Valid
Run Time Value                  : 177843221492583
Run Time Scale                  : 1000000000
Run Time Epoch                  : 0
Acceleration Vector             : 0.008651109405 -0.003601103323 -1.025277733
Sub Sec Time Original           : 185
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 185
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : Uncalibrated
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 26 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Lens Info                       : 1.539999962-6mm f/1.8-2.4
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPhone 11 Pro back triple camera 4.25mm f/1.8
Composite Image                 : General Composite Image
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : East
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Speed Ref                   : km/h
GPS Speed                       : 0
GPS Img Direction Ref           : True North
GPS Img Direction               : 71.31763456
GPS Dest Bearing Ref            : True North
GPS Dest Bearing                : 71.31763456
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2021:06:15
GPS Horizontal Positioning Error: 65 m
Profile CMM Type                : Apple Computer Inc.
Profile Version                 : 4.0.0
Profile Class                   : Display Device Profile
Color Space Data                : RGB
Profile Connection Space        : XYZ
Profile Date Time               : 2017:07:07 13:22:32
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : Apple Computer Inc.
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Apple Computer Inc.
Profile ID                      : ca1a9582257f104d389913d5d1ea1582
Profile Description             : Display P3
Profile Copyright               : Copyright Apple Inc., 2017
Media White Point               : 0.95045 1 1.08905
Red Matrix Column               : 0.51512 0.2412 -0.00105
Green Matrix Column             : 0.29198 0.69225 0.04189
Blue Matrix Column              : 0.1571 0.06657 0.78407
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Chromatic Adaptation            : 1.04788 0.02292 -0.0502 0.02959 0.99048 -0.01706 -0.00923 0.01508 0.75168
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 3024
Image Height                    : 4032
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:4:4 (1 1)
Run Time Since Power Up         : 2 days 1:24:03
Aperture                        : 1.8
Image Size                      : 3024x4032
Megapixels                      : 12.2
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 6.1
Shutter Speed                   : 1/60
Create Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12.185+02:00
Date/Time Original              : 2021:06:15 17:59:12.185+02:00
Modify Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12+02:00
GPS Altitude                    : 255.7 m Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 49 deg 59' 50.66" N
GPS Longitude                   : 14 deg 25' 29.76" E
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.005 mm
Field Of View                   : 69.4 deg
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm (35 mm equivalent: 26.0 mm)
GPS Position                    : 49 deg 59' 50.66" N, 14 deg 25' 29.76" E
Hyperfocal Distance             : 2.04 m
Light Value                     : 7.3
Lens ID                         : iPhone 11 Pro back triple camera 4.25mm f/1.8
```

The metadata of the corrupted file c.heic:

```
c.heic: ISO Media, HEIF Image HEVC Main or Main Still Picture Profile


ExifTool Version Number         : 12.26
File Name                       : c.heic
Directory                       : /Users/pepa/Downloads/imageTests/a
File Size                       : 1592 KiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:06:21 14:53:11+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:06:21 14:55:02+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:06:21 14:55:01+02:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : HEIC
File Type Extension             : heic
MIME Type                       : image/heic
Major Brand                     : High Efficiency Image Format HEVC still image (.HEIC)
Minor Version                   : 0.0.0
Compatible Brands               : mif1, heic
Handler Type                    : Picture
Primary Item Reference          : 1
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
White Balance                   : Auto
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPhone 11 Pro
Software                        : 14.0.1
Modify Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Exposure Time                   : 1/60
F Number                        : 1.8
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 125
Exif Version                    : 0231
Date/Time Original              : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Create Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12
Offset Time                     : +02:00
Offset Time Original            : +02:00
Offset Time Digitized           : +02:00
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/60
Aperture Value                  : 1.8
Brightness Value                : 3.03912093
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Flash                           : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm
Subject Area                    : 2002 1505 2213 1324
Run Time Flags                  : Valid
Run Time Value                  : 177843221492583
Run Time Scale                  : 1000000000
Run Time Epoch                  : 0
Acceleration Vector             : 0.008651109405 -0.003601103323 -1.025277733
Sub Sec Time Original           : 185
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 185
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : Uncalibrated
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Sensing Method                  : One-chip color area
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 26 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Lens Info                       : 1.539999962-6mm f/1.8-2.4
Lens Make                       : Apple
Lens Model                      : iPhone 11 Pro back triple camera 4.25mm f/1.8
Composite Image                 : General Composite Image
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : East
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Speed Ref                   : km/h
GPS Speed                       : 0
GPS Img Direction Ref           : True North
GPS Img Direction               : 71.31763456
GPS Dest Bearing Ref            : True North
GPS Dest Bearing                : 71.31763456
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2021:06:15
GPS Horizontal Positioning Error: 65 m
HEVC Configuration Version      : 1
General Profile Space           : Conforming
General Tier Flag               : Main Tier
General Profile IDC             : Main Still Picture
Gen Profile Compatibility Flags : Main Still Picture, Main 10, Main
Constraint Indicator Flags      : 0 0 0 0 0 0
General Level IDC               : 180 (level 6.0)
Min Spatial Segmentation IDC    : 0
Parallelism Type                : 0
Chroma Format                   : 4:2:0
Bit Depth Luma                  : 8
Bit Depth Chroma                : 8
Average Frame Rate              : 0
Constant Frame Rate             : Unknown
Num Temporal Layers             : 1
Temporal ID Nested              : Yes
Color Representation            : nclx 2 2 6
Image Pixel Depth               : 8 8 8
Media Data Size                 : 1629724
Media Data Offset               : 470
Run Time Since Power Up         : 2 days 1:24:03
Aperture                        : 1.8
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 6.1
Shutter Speed                   : 1/60
Create Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12.185+02:00
Date/Time Original              : 2021:06:15 17:59:12.185+02:00
Modify Date                     : 2021:06:15 17:59:12+02:00
GPS Altitude                    : 255.7 m Above Sea Level
GPS Latitude                    : 49 deg 59' 50.66" N
GPS Longitude                   : 14 deg 25' 29.76" E
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.005 mm
Field Of View                   : 69.4 deg
Focal Length                    : 4.2 mm (35 mm equivalent: 26.0 mm)
GPS Position                    : 49 deg 59' 50.66" N, 14 deg 25' 29.76" E
Hyperfocal Distance             : 2.04 m
Light Value                     : 7.3
Lens ID                         : iPhone 11 Pro back triple camera 4.25mm f/1.8
```

ImageMagick --version

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-59 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-24 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
```

In other words, each time the output is HEIC is the output corrupted. Any idea why?

Comment: Your ImageMagick version is rather old. Perhaps you need to upgrade as HEIC has been in continual development. Also you de not say what version of libheic that you are using. Perhaps that needs upgrading.

Comment: If after upgrading ImageMagick and libheic to the most current, your problem persists, please post a bug report to the issues forum at ImageMagick GIT website at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues

Comment: What exactly is corrupted in the output HEIC meta data?

Comment: metadata is fine, it's the content what was corrupted. See the "preview" error message. Now solved by the upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to latest 7.1.0 version solved the issue.